# How can i handle dynamically an event for checkboxes(are created with dynamic id) with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JavaScript code**

==============

*I have created a SP online list*
getting categories and subcategories, each of these has to be checkbox so I gave them a unique id dynamically(category name), my purpose is when the user clicks on one of them to alert 'clicked'.

```js
function getItem(listUrl) {

$.ajax({strong text
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + listUrl,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: (data) => {

                var newsHTML = "";
                var news = {}

                var items = data.d.results;

                console.log(items)
                items.map((item) => {

                    var category = item.Category.Title

                    if (news[category] == null) {
                        news[category] = [];
                    }
                    var data = {
                        subcategory: item.Subcategory.Title,
                        description: item.Description
                    }

                    news[category].push(data)
                })

                for (let i in news) {
                    newsHTML += '<input id="' + i + '"" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /> ' + i + '<br> <ul>';

                    let checkValue = $('#' + i + '').is(":checked");
                    console.log(checkValue)
                    for (let j in news[i]) {
                        newsHTML += '<input id="' + news[i][j].subcategory + '"" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /> ' + news[i][j].subcategory + '<br>'
                    }
                    newsHTML += "</ul>";
                }

                $("#news").html(newsHTML);
                console.log(news)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the actual question?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) mechanism. It allows you to handle all checkboxes without setting additional ids or smth else.

```
$('#news').on('.change', 'input[name="myCheckbox"]', function(e){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Just add this event handler after your ajax call and it will handle all your dynamical checkboxe's changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the event handlers separately. Make the following changes:

```
for (let j in news[i]) {
  newsHTML += '<input id="' + news[i][j].subcategory + '"" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" onClick="clickFunction()"/> ' + news[i][j].subcategory + '<br>'
}

function clickFunction(){
    .
    . perform click event handler operation
    . use event object to access the correct options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Really sorry,**

**solution :**

```
<input onclick="ifUserClicked()" id="' + i + '"" type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" /> ' + i + '<br> <ul>
```

I have to create ifUserClicked() outside of getItem(). :(